# How do I configure routing for non-knative service in a Knative & Istio installed k8 cluster?

Tags: istio

I have a Knative installed with Istio as networking layer (without injection)
The kubernetes cluster is using Istio ingress gateway as default ingress.
Most Knative service's routing are managed automatically by Knative & Istio.

However I am trying to run a nifi native kubernetes services on the same cluster, how do I setup the ingress configuration on Istio ingress gateway for the services. Any reference to share?

Or is it possible to setup 2 ingress (1 Istio, 1 nginx) in the cluster, and have the native k8 service uses the nginx ingress?

I'm doing that cause istio is quite new to me and Knative abstracted the Istio networking element when deploying knative services but not the native k8 services.

Hope my question makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: Hello @Darkbluelion. Does any of the below answers helped you?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the standard Istio [VirtualService](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/) object to map domains to Kubernetes Services (as described in the Istio documentation), assuming that you don't overlap with a domain already being served by Knative.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I configure routing for non-knative service in a Knative & Istio installed k8 cluster?

Just like you would in istio-only cluster (without knative).

knative works like an addon; it adds some functionality; it does not remove/hide any istio functionality. Same is with istio - it adds more functionality to k8s and does not remove any k8s core functionality. You can use all the features of istio and k8s all the time.

---

> how do I setup the ingress configuration on Istio ingress gateway for the services

Check out the [bookinfo example](https://istio.io/latest/docs/examples/bookinfo/). This example deploys a sample application composed of four separate microservices used to demonstrate various Istio features. Try to analyze it.

---

> is it possible to setup 2 ingress (1 Istio, 1 nginx) in the cluster, and have the native k8 service uses the nginx ingress?

Yes. It is possible.